# Passing text from one worksheet to another using an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, transpose

I'm trying to pass data from sheet 3 to sheet 4 based on a criterion (*). With numbers results but with text the program fails.
How to overcome this situation when instead of a number I have text.

```
Public Sub TestArray3()
    'Array to copy data from Sheet3 to Sheet4 Based on criterion "in this case*"
    Dim tempVar As Integer, anotherIteration As Boolean, i As Integer
    Dim J As Integer, ArraySize As Integer, myArray() As Integer
    Dim newArray() As Integer, FinalRow As Integer, linha As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer, cel1 As Range

    Sheets("Folha3").Select
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Find the last row of data
    ArraySize = FinalRow 'Get Array Size
    ReDim myArray(ArraySize - 1)
    For linha = 1 To FinalRow
        Set cel1 = Cells(linha, 1)
        If cel1 = "*" Then
            myArray(linha - 1) = Val(Cells(linha, "B").Value) 'Populate de Array
        End If
    Next linha

    ReDim newArray(LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)) 'Avoid zeros in Array
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If myArray(i) <> "0" Then
            J = J + 1
            newArray(J) = myArray(i)
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve newArray(LBound(myArray) To J)
    ArraySize = J
    Sheets("Folha4").Select 'Write data to Sheet 4 column A
    Range("A1").Resize(J - LBound(newArray) + 1)=Application.Transpose(newArray)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you use an unqualified Val(...) conversion if you are expecting text?

Comment: Do you mean to use Val so that text are zeroes?

Comment: Which range are you trying to copy, and to where?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear on where you're actually trying to paste from/to, but here's one [of several] ways to move data between worksheets, including both with and without transposing

Hopefully this example should clear up the steps:

```
Sub copyRangeToOtherSheet()

    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, rgSrc As Range, rgDest As Range, arr() As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")                               'set source worksheet

        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row              'find last row of Col A
        lastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column      'find last col of Row 1
        Set rgSrc = Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))    'create range (from A1)

    End With

    arr = rgSrc                                                      'dump range into array

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")                               'set destination sheet

      'OPTION #1: Populate destination in "original" orientation
        Set rgDest = .Range("A1")                           'set destination top-left corner
        Set rgDest = rgDest.Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2))  'fit to array rows/col's
        rgDest = arr                                          'dump array to worksheet range

      'OPTION #2: Populate destination in "transposed" orientation
        Set rgDest = .Range("D1")                           'set destination top-left corner
        Set rgDest = rgDest.Resize(UBound(arr, 2), UBound(arr, 1))  'fit to array col's/rows
        rgDest = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)  'dump transposed array to worksheet range

    End With

End Sub
```

Note that it's easiest if you don't set the size of the array in advance — Excel will size it automatically as long as the array isn't already dimensioned (which is why it's declared only as `arr() As Variant`).

On the destination end, we can pick one cell as the top-left of the range, then [`ReSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) the range based on the arrays' upper bounds ([`UBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function)).

If we are going to [`Transpose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose) the cells, we must **swap the number of rows/columns** in the destination range.

[image: img]

---

### More Information:

- One resource I've found very helpful is Chip Pearson's [**VBA Arrays And Worksheet Ranges**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your help but, I have in sheet 1 in column A I have * and in column B I have string. I want to copy every time I find the * the macro copy from sheet1 the string to sheet 2. When I execute the macro the system see the string with 0.

Answer (score 0):

## String vs Integer

It is a little unclear what is happening here, but I have noticed that you have declared all your arrays as **integer** so you cannot pass **strings** to them. Try to find out which array you're trying to pass strings to and declare it as **variant** or implement some 'conditional' code like:

```
If Not IsNumeric(Cells("A1").Value) then
  Variable = 0
End If
```

Read **ashleedawg**'s guidelines.

You don't have to select a worksheet to do stuff to it (referring to **Select**). You can write

```
FinalRow = Sheets("Folha3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

or

```
Sheets("Folha4").Range("A1").Resize(J - LBound(newArray) + 1) _
= Application.Transpose(newArray)
```

and save a line but more importantly, not jump around in the workboook. Even better is using **With**:

```
With Sheets("Folha3")
    FinalRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Find the last row of data
    ArraySize = FinalRow 'Get Array Size
    ReDim myArray(ArraySize - 1)
    For linha = 1 To FinalRow
        Set cel1 = .Cells(linha, 1)
        If cel1 = "*" Then
            myArray(linha - 1) = Val(.Cells(linha, "B").Value) 'Populate de Array
        End If
    Next linha
End With
```

Notice the '**.**' in front of each cells (.cells), it is referring to the sheet object.

Try using variables for objects. When you write

```
Sheets("folha3").
```

nothing happens you have to remember what it can do. But if you assign it to a variable the intelliSense is activated and you can see the properties and methods of objects e.g.

```
Dim oWb as Workbook
Dim oWs as Worksheet
Set oWb = Activeworkbook
Set oWs = oWb.Sheets("Folha3")
```

Now when you write:

```
oWs.
```

the IntelliSense shows you the properties and methods of the worksheet object e.g. Activate, Cells, Copy, Delete, Paste etc.

With a few more lines of code you will learn much more.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your advise. I used your code (using with) by declaring an array at the beginning but I can't get the macro to read the string, the value is always 0. How to solve?

Comment: My answer's first sentence says you have declared your arrays as integer which is wrong, if you want to pass strings. If you want to pass strings to an array you should declare it as string: Dim SomeArray() as String. Even better is just Dim SomeArray() what is translated to Dim SomeArray() as Variant, then you can pass what ever value you want.